# Get Metadata from audio stream with AVAUDIOPLAYER

Tags: ios, audio, metadata, avaudioplayer

I would like to retrieve metadata (song, artist) from an audio stream with AVAUDIOPLAYER. I tried with this code, but i dont get any data from multiple URL.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
NSMutableDictionary *songInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (NSString *format in [asset availableMetadataFormats])
```

Coud someone help me? maybe i did wrong? AVAUDIOPLAYER is available to do that?

Thanks

Comment: I would use `AVPlayer` instead of `AVAudioPlayer`, then you can create an `AVPlayerItem` and associate that with an instance of `AVPlayer`. Metadata on the item can be retrieved by using its properties such as `tracks` and `duration`. [here are the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/index.html) . if you want additonal meta data not provided by `AVPlayerItem` then you can first create an `AVAsset`, and retrieve the additional data from that object. You would then create an `AVPlayerItem` from the `AVAsset`

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Any solutions with Avaudioplayer? maybe its not possible to get metadata with ..????

Comment: None that I am aware of

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to create an `AVAsset` and use it to create an `AVPlayerItem` which can then be associated with an instance of `AVPlayer`. Metadata can be retrieved by using properties of the `AVAsset` ...

```
var player = AVPlayer()      
func createAssetAndItem(){

    //create AVAsset from an NSURL. metadata can be retrieved from the asset depending on what is available
let createdAVAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: songNSURL)

    //create an AVPlayerItem from the AVAsset
let createdAVItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: createdAVAsset)

    //asscoaite AVPlayerItem with instance of AVPlayer
player = AVPlayer(AVPlayerItem: createdAVItem)


}
```

Comment: Doesnt work :( im desperate now . i dont find any solutions

Comment: are you now working with `AVPlayer`? We need to see your code pertaining to your attempt but you should probably open a new question for this. Also where are you getting the audio file from? perhaps the meta data is not proivided

Comment: I answered, sorry for the time i took.